# How to install php5.6 to develop extension on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: php, c

I am struggling trying to install `php5.6` to develop my own extension on c language, I am using `ubuntu 14.04 lt`s and `apache/2.4.7`
What I want to know is a reliable way to install `php5.6` to add extension

Comment: Actually, trying to compile packages on outdated platforms is a common problem and trying to install updates piecemeal on older versions is a fraught (and usually futile) process so, for what it's worth, I'd say it's a useful question to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the repository for Ubuntu 15.10, php5-dev is version 5.6.11 according to the changelog. If your problem involves installing that, you will almost certainly have to upgrade.

The problem with LTS is that your versions and dependencies fall further and further behind. If you're a developer, sticking with the old version is not an option. I found this out the hard way!